# Moving rows of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like this, I want to move some rows among Matrix

```
Matrix = 
[ 1   101   201   301
  2   102   202   302
  3   103   203   303
  4   104   204   304
  5   105   205   305
  6   106   206   306
  7   107   207   307
  8   108   208   308
  9   109   209   309
  10   110   210   310];
```

for example, I want to move row number 6 after row number 2

```
Matrix = 
         [ 1   101   201   301
           2   102   202   302
           6   106   206   306
           3   103   203   303
           4   104   204   304
           5   105   205   305
           7   107   207   307
           8   108   208   308
           9   109   209   309
           10   110   210   310];
```

then I want to move row 9 after row 5

```
 Matrix = 
         [ 1   101   201   301
           2   102   202   302
           6   106   206   306
           3   103   203   303
           4   104   204   304
           5   105   205   305
           9   109   209   309
           7   107   207   307
           8   108   208   308
           10   110   210   310];
```

How can I accomplish this in Matlab?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please consider accepting the answer, if it helped you, by clicking the green check mark on the left. This way you indicate the system that your problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just by indexing:

```
Matrix = ...
[ 1   101   201   301
  2   102   202   302
  3   103   203   303
  4   104   204   304
  5   105   205   305
  6   106   206   306
  7   107   207   307
  8   108   208   308
  9   109   209   309
  10   110   210   310];

newOrder = [1 2 6 3 4 5 9 7 8 10];
out = Matrix(newOrder,:)
```

---

```
out =

     1   101   201   301
     2   102   202   302
     6   106   206   306
     3   103   203   303
     4   104   204   304
     5   105   205   305
     9   109   209   309
     7   107   207   307
     8   108   208   308
    10   110   210   310
```